# How do you use Fetch API to get coordinates to put markers on google-maps-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I'm new to React and I'm trying to get coordinates from an external database to put markers on google maps. I have tried to use Fetch API to get the coordinates but it returns a promise, so  the map doesn't get the coordinates before it renders. I use the following code:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import {
  GoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} from "react-google-maps";
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

Geocode.setApiKey("API_KEY");

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
const database_url_coordinates = "DATABASE_URL_COORDINATES";

function Map() {
  Geocode.setApiKey("API_KEY");
  Geocode.enableDebug();
  const [selectedKalas, setSelectedKalas] = useState(null);

  function Lat() {
    return parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("user_lat"));
  }

  function Lng() {
    return parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("user_lng"));
  }

  window
    .fetch(database_url_coordinates)
    .then(response => {
      return response;
    })
    .then(data => {
      return (
        <GoogleMap
          defaultOptions={{
            streetViewControl: false,
            minZoom: 5,
            maxZoom: 15,
            styles: [
              {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "labels.text",
                stylers: [
                  {
                    visibility: "off"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "labels.icon",
                stylers: [
                  {
                    visibility: "off"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }}
          defaultZoom={13}
          defaultCenter={{ lat: 63.418827, lng: 10.402732 }}
          style={{ width: "100vw", height: "70vh" }}
        >
          <Marker
            key={localStorage.getItem("kalas_id")}
            position={{
              lat: data[1].lat,
              lng: data[1].lng
            }}
            icon={{
              url:
                "https://www.rr-a.no/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/map-marker-icon.png",
              scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(50, 50)
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedKalas(localStorage.getItem("kalas_id"));
            }}
          />
          {selectedKalas && (
            <InfoWindow
              position={{
                lat: Lat(),
                lng: Lng()
              }}
              onCloseClick={() => {
                setSelectedKalas(null);
              }}
            >
              <div>
                <h2>Ditt Kalas!</h2>
                <p>Kalasnavn: {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("username"))}</p>
                <p>
                  Kapasitiet: {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("capacity"))}
                </p>
                <p>
                  Adresse: {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("address"))},{" "}
                  {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("postal"))}
                </p>
                <p>
                  Telefonnr.: {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("phoneNumber"))}
                </p>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          )}
        </GoogleMap>
      );
    });
}

class MapClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      latiude: null,
      longitude: null,
      userAdress: null,
      allMarkers: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: "100vw", heigth: "100vh" }}>
        <WrappedMap
          googleMapURL={
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
          }
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `70vh` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MapClass;
```

I have replaced the API_KEY and DATABASE_URL_COORDINATES. 
The error message i get is:

```
Uncaught Error: Map(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

I'd appreciate any feedback!

Comment: You must return something from the component, even if that is `null`. Putting the fetch request in the body of the function with no condition means it will be called every render if it didn't break first. Consider using `useEffect` to fetch the data, and setting the data to a stateful variable with `useState`. Then return the `GoogleMap` from the component, and not from the fetch request.

Comment: Thanks Brian! The useEffect method did the trick